# XSLT 1.0 not(contains in for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, contains

I want to include this:

```
not(contains(country/product/@genericname, 'Color Purple'))
```

in this `for-each`

```
<xsl:for-each select="country[@name = 'GB']/product[@category = 'inkjet' and contains(@classification, 'consumer') or contains(@classification, 'businessinkjet')]">
```

I tried this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="not(contains(country/product/@genericname, 'Stylus Pro')) and country[@name = $country]/product[@category = 'inkjet' and contains(@classification, 'consumer') or contains(@classification, 'businessinkjet')]">
```

But, I get this error: `The value is not a node-set`. I don't see the syntax error.

Processor: Saxon6.5.5

@michael.hor257k

I adapted your snippet, look hier the right for-each with params of mine.

```
<xsl:param name="country">GB</xsl:param>
<xsl:for-each select="country[@name = $country]/product[@category = 'inkjet' and contains(@classification, 'consumer') or contains(@classification, 'businessinkjet')] [not(contains(country/product/@genericname, 'Stylus Pro'))]">
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<countries>
    <country name="GB">
        <product genericname="Yellow line" id="12345" />
        <product genericname="Red line" id="6789" type="device" />
        <product genericname="This is Stylus Pro" id="256464" />
    </country>
</countries>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the right way, thanks, is was the wrong path.

```
<xsl:for-each select="country[@name = 'GB']/product[@category = 'inkjet' and contains(@classification, 'consumer') or contains(@classification, 'businessinkjet')] [not(contains(**@genericname**, 'Stylus Pro'))]">
```

not **country/product/@genericname**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`not(contains())` needs to be in a *predicate* (inside square brackets). Outside of the predicate/s, you need to have a path leading to a node. Post an example of your XML code for a more specific answer.

I am guessing this may be what you want:

```
<xsl:for-each select="country[@name = 'GB']/product[@category = 'inkjet' and contains(@classification, 'consumer') or contains(@classification, 'businessinkjet')] [not(contains(@genericname, 'Color Purple'))]">
```

Note that the path points to `product`, and the predicates limit the classes of products to be included in the selection.

---

### Edit:

XSLT is very context-sensitive.

```
[not(contains(@genericname, 'Stylus Pro'))]
```

is **very** different from:

```
[not(contains(country/product/@genericname, 'Stylus Pro'))]
```

The first one looks at the `genericname` attribute of the **current node**. In the context of:

```
select="country[...]/product[...]"
```

the current node is `product`.

The second one looks at the `genericname` attribute of a node named `product` that is a child of `country` that is a child of the current node. This attribute does not exist - so of course it does not contain the search string.

Comment: @Stefan Well, does it select products that **do** contain "Color Purple" in their `genericname` attribute?

Comment: @Stefan Please do not post code in comments; edit your question instead. -- I am not sure if you've seen my comment: the code you are using is **not** the code I have posted.

Comment: im learning... i posted the real code with my adaptions
My target is: I want to exclude Stylus Pro